# How to display time ago when specific table columns updated?

Tags: reactjs

I want to show the time ago when the `latitude` and `longitude` last updated  in my table.

My code currently shows the time ago of last update (through web 
socket). It doesn't show the time ago that the `latitude` or `longitude` specifically were updated. How can I solve this? [Here is a screen-shot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbcdV.png), and the code is below:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let socket = new WebSocket('ws://139.162.2.53:9988');
  this.setState({ socket: socket });
  this.getSupportInfo();
  socket.onmessage = ((message) => {
    let socketData = JSON.parse(message.data);
    //console.log(socketData[0] );
    let device_id = socketData[0].device_id;
    let updatedSupportInfo = this.state.supportInfo;
    let now = new Date();
    let uSupport = updatedSupportInfo.map(function(item){
     if(device_id == item.device_id){
       // console.log(item);
       item.current_pos = socketData[0].current_pos;
       item["latlng"] = item.current_pos.x + ',' + item.current_pos.y;
       let time = new Date(socketData[0].timestamp)
       let a = moment(time);
       let b = moment(now);
       //let timeAgo = a.from(b);
       let timeAgo = b.diff(a, 'minutes')
       //console.log("a", a);
       //console.log("b", b);
       //console.log("timeAgo", timeAgo);
       item["timeAgo"] = timeAgo;
     }
     return item;
    });
    this.setState({supportInfo:uSupport})
  });
}
```

I am using react bootstrap table:

```
<TableHeaderColumn dataField="timeAgo" dataSort={true}>Time Ago(mins)</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Comment: Hi @Pawan, I'm guessing English is not your first language, as the original question was very unclear. I have tried to improve the grammar and formatting for you, but could you please review the post to ensure I did not misinterpret your question? Thanks.